# Error: Run-From-Zip is set to a remote URL using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE Azure Function with deployed DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, cicd

I have a problem here, I need to generate CICD Azure Function on Azure DevOps. First of all, I'm deployed manually Azure Function on my vscode. Then I try to CICD using Azure DevOps, it was deployed successfully, but however, when I try it again to deploy manually on my vscode, I got an error like this.

```
Run-From-Zip is set to a remote URL using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE or WEBSITE_USE_ZIP app setting. 
Deployment is not supported in this configuration.
```

What happens to my Azure DevOps?
This is the link of reference that I use to CICD my Azure Function [CICD Link](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-build-ci-cd-for-python-azure-functions-using-azure-devops-7087a76e535b)

Comment: Make `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting to 0 or Remove this `WEBSITE_USE_ZIP` app setting in Function Configuration in the portal and try!

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT where is this configuration ?

Comment: Azure Portal > your Function App > Configuration under Settings (Left Index) > Application Settings

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Thanks, so this package will always be replaced when I deployed it using Azure DevOps?

Comment: Once the setting is removed, it will not come again until you manually add the same setting newly!

Comment: Any update on the issue?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Hi, I'm sorry for the late response, it is clear now. Thank you!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241036/discussion-between-harikrishnarajoli-mt-and-rudy-tri-saputra).

Comment: Is removing of that setting worked for you?

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT Hmm, actually no, when I deep dive to my problem by checking on the Azure Function log, there was an error from the module package not found, it actually cause of Azure DevOps python version 3.6 didn't provide to deploy the package into worker, so I change the python version to 3.8 to follow up the ubuntu verison 20.04

Comment: Can I Convert the resolution to an answer so that this thread will be closed and helpful to other community members?

Comment: Yeah, you can actually convert that has you defined before (Set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE into 0)

Answer (score 3):

Glad [Rudy Tri Saputra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10660847/rudy-tri-saputra), that you identified it was the module package error and resolved by updating your environment python version to 3.8 to follow up the ubuntu version 20.04.

> Run-From-Zip is set to a remote URL using WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE or WEBSITE_USE_ZIP app setting.
> Deployment is not supported in this configuration.

For this kind of error, one of the workarounds is to make `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting to `0` or Remove this `WEBSITE_USE_ZIP` app setting in **Function Configuration** under the **settings** menu in the Azure portal.

Comment: I encountered this issue as well and setting `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to `0` worked. 

As detailed above, I do believe the root cause of this issue is caused by using Azure Functions Deployment task. By default, it will set `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` to a url. When I look at the Azure Devops logs, I see 
`Trying to update App Service Application settings. Data: {"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE":"https://[redacted].blob.core.windows.net/azure-pipelines-deploy/package_1648606705533.zip?***"}`

Comment: Yes, @burnt1ce, you can set the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` setting to `URL` if you want to run the Function with the specific package file which is in the remote endpoint/location when Azure Functions is running on the Linux Consumption plan, it is the best option but in Windows OS - it's not recommended as it gives worse cold start performance. and more information available. Refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#enable-functions-to-run-from-a-package).